# how to ensure untouched HTML for every test with mocha and phantomjs on node

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, phantomjs, mocha.js

I wrote an webapplication where I want to do some DOM testing from commandline using mocha and phantomjs and I am trying to figure out the best way to do that.

As the webapplication is doing a lot of DOM manipulations I want to be able to load the DOM completely new for every test. I tried to use the [webpage module of phantomjs](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/) but I don't know how to run the mocha tests on the page then (or if this is the correct way to do it).

Of course I could just create a file `test.html` where I include mocha via script tag and then run `phantomjs test.html`. But how can I ensure then that the DOM is untouched on every test? Adding one HTML file for each test with the same content would be a nightmare to support.

What I have so far:

my testrunner.js:

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
    expect = require('expect.js'),
    fs    = require('fs'),
    path  = require('path');

var mocha = new Mocha(
{
  ui: 'bdd'
});
// I only add one file for now
mocha.addFile(
  path.join(__dirname, 'tests_integration/test.js')
);

mocha.run(function(failures){
  process.on('exit', function () {
    process.exit(failures);
  });
});
```

My test.js: 
This is where I struggle because I cannot figure out how to run the tests inside the page:

```
var phantom = require('phantom');
phantom.create(function (ph) {
  ph.createPage(function (page) {
    page.open("http://test.local", function (status) {
      page.evaluate(function (tests) {
        // here I need to run my tests, which obviously doesnt work that way
        describe('DOM tests',function(){
          it('should be able to acces the page',function(){
            expect(document.body).not.to.be(undefined)
          });
        });
        return document.body
      }.bind(tests), function (html) {
        ph.exit();
      });
    });
  });
});
```

To run the tests I exec `node integration-runner.js`. One solution I thought of would be to use [includeJS](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/include-js.html) to inject mocha into the phantom-page, but that seems kinda hacky to me.

Am I doing it completely wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some research and talking to other developers it seems that creating different HTML files would be the cleanest solution. However, as I dont want to update all those files manually whenever I change my webapp, I decided to go with the injectJS solution [as described in this great post](http://doublenegative.com/phantomjs-mocha-and-chai-for-functional-testing/).

Now I can dynamically inject mocha testfiles into the live site and run them.